# CSOM Field.FromBaseType returns false, although the field is derived from another content type

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom

I retrieve the FieldCollection of a content type via client side object model:

```
var fields = contentType.Fields;
clientContext.Load(fields);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Then I cycle through the fields and check if the field is derived:

```
if (field.FromBaseType) { ... }
```

This works for the field "Title" which is derived from "Item", but not for fields the content type has derived from another custom content type.

Why is `FromBaseType` true for the "Title" field, but not for the fields of the direct parent content type? And how can I find out, if a field is derived?

Answer (score 0):

As Vadim said, the [Field.FromBaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field.frombasetype%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property does only indicate if the field derives from a base field type. It says nothing about the content type.

So, I solved my problem by loading the fields of the parent content type, too and checking if they contain a field with the same ID:

```
var fields = contentType.Fields;
var parentFields = contentType.Parent.Fields;
clientContext.Load(fields);
clientContext.Load(parentFields);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var field in fields)
{
    if (Enumerable.Any(parentFields, pf => pf.Id == field.Id))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But this is kind of crude ... if someone has a better answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately the verification of field from parent content type is not enough due to hierarchical structure of content type

Comment: Why? I remind you, I only want to check *if* the field is derived, not *from which* content type it is derived.

Comment: Ok, probably i see your point now, it seems you dont need to know actually what is the source content type of field, the example in my answer it is demonstrated how to determine the source content type of field (the same that displays in Content Type management page)

Comment: just for the sake of completeness, from your question i originally considered that you would like to determine the source content type of field

Answer (score 0):

[SPField.FromBaseType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.frombasetype.aspx) gets a Boolean value that indicates whether the field derives from a base field type and it is not the same as determining whether the field derives from parent content type.

The following method demonstrates how o determine the source content type of a field:

```
public static ContentType GetSource(Field field, ContentType contentType)
{  
     var ctx = field.Context;
     var parentCt = contentType.Parent;
     ctx.Load(parentCt);
     ctx.Load(parentCt.FieldLinks);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     var fieldLink = parentCt.FieldLinks.FirstOrDefault(fl => fl.Name == field.InternalName);
     if (parentCt.StringId != "0x01" && fieldLink != null)
     {
         return GetSource(field, parentCt);
     }
     return (fieldLink == null ?  contentType : parentCt);
}
```

Usage

```
var fields = contentType.Fields;
ctx.Load(fields);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var field in fields)
{
     var source = GetSource(field, contentType);
     Console.WriteLine("Field: {0} Source: {1}",field.Title,source.Name);
}
```